# use a variable in bootstrap 2.3.2 popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

With the below code I expect to see a popover with the name of the product as title.

```
    $('.btn-blue').click(function(){            
      var btnName = $(this).parents('.individual-content').children('.name').html();
      //alert(btnName);
      $(this).popover({title: btnName,content: "<p>Added to cart!</p>", html: true, placement: "bottom"});
    });
```

When I uncomment the `alert` it shows the title in the alert so the variable is correct. 
But the popover still gets triggered with the default title. And not with `btnName`.

I made a fiddle that has everything in it for quick reference.
https://jsfiddle.net/gr19fmcu/

**2 questions**

Why is it still displaying the default title and not the variable content?

Why do I need to double click to see the popover at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get it to work with the above code. The code seems to me to be correct and I got no clue why it ain't working. Anyhow I needed it for a Joomla website and resorted back in using the System Messages from Joomla itself.

I triggered it with this code:

```
$('.btn-blue').click(function(){
      var btnName = $(this).parents('.individual-content').children('.name').html();
      Joomla.renderMessages({"success":[btnName + " is being added to your cart!"]});
    });
```

The result is even better then I expected. Anyhow, I leave the question open as I still hope someone to shed some light over why the original code is not working.